# Chrome auto-complete the wrong from field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, browser, autocomplete, passwords

I am using Devise for authentication

In the settings I have 3 fields:

password (for entering a new password)

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="controls" id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password">
```

password confirmation

```
<input class="controls" id="user_password_confirmation" name="user[password_confirmation]" size="30" type="password">
```

current password

```
<input class="controls" id="user_current_password" name="user[current_password]" size="30" type="password">
```

I want the current password to be autocompleted but chrome autocomplete the password confirmation for some reason

Is there a way to tell chrome which field is the password field to be autocompleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set autocomplete="off" only on user_password. Maybe you should set it where you want them to be.